# Caffe transfer subset of parameters

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I want to take out a subset of *`n`* parameters in a given layer from a trained network **`A`**, and transfer this subset into a layer of another network **`B`**. 
In the layer to which this subset is transferred, the remaining parameters of said layer *(total - transferred subset)* should be randomly initialized.

Is this achievable? 
(I know it can be done with whole layers of parameters)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in python. See [net surgery tutorial](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/net_surgery.ipynb).
Basically, you should instantiate two `caffe.Net` objects one with parameters of `A` and the other with random. Then you simply assign the subset of parameters from `A` to `B`, saves `B` and you are done.